# Oracle ORA-00054 but probably no locks

Tags: oracle, locks, ora-00054

I have a legacy code that is doing the following:

```
ALTER TABLE A RENAME TO B;
ALTER TABLE C RENAME TO A;
ALTER TABLE B RENAME TO C;
```

It is swapping 2 tables A and C.

The problem: the third alter table DDL throws the error:

ORA-00054 RESOURCE BUSY

I do not understand how it's possible that there is a lock after the first two DDLs? At this point every transaction should be already commited.

It happens quite often but not always - sometimes it works, sometimes not.

There is no chance that some other session altered this tables data during the swap - first of all it's very short operation, secondly - only one table (table A) is really used, second one is more like archive so nobody is performing any DML on it. And even if we assume to unlikely scenario that someone indeed managed to connect and lock something - it's such a short time that I could understand if it happened once, but it is happening after every 2-3 swaps.

I have no clue. Is it possible that after renaming table some old locks are still active?

thanks

Comment: Try adding a `/` after each `ALTER`.

Answer (score 0):

After the second statement runs, but before the third statement runs some other session could take a lock on table `B` (or potentially a child or parent table or a dependent PL/SQL package, etc).